# SQL query problems using CASE

Tags: mysql, case

I have a database with 2 types of users, a user can either be an `individual` or `organization` which are children of the parent user `user`, reason I did this is because there are attributes an organization has that an `individual` do not have, unlike having single table where all the attributes for both users can be defined and having to have empty fields I decided to create a `user` table which has the common attributes between the two types of users, then there is a column which keeps the user type, so if its `1` then the user is an individual so I have to look in the `individual` table for all the other attributes vice versa, the `individual` and `organization` tables hold the `user foreign key` to have it identified here is a graphical representation of my database tables 
[image]

Incase you are wondering why I did not make one table, I plan on adding more attributes to both the user and organization tables as the app grows, am leaving room for expansion, so here is my problem, I want to get a user's data, I have their ID already, but how can I check the userType and point to the right table for the next set of attributes, for example if a user named John whose Id is 2 and is in the individual table how do I get their first and last name?

my idea of the query is like:

```
Select users.email, users.profilePhoto, users.userSince, CASE WHEN userType = 1 THEN SELECT individual.fname, individual.lname WHERE users.id = 1 AND individual.userFK = 1 END FROM users
```

But am not familiar with the `CASE` statement so I always get an error, anyone who would like to help, you are most welcome.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: @coder I have looked at your link, its educational but right now what I need is a query if one can help, then from there I will learn where I was going wrong

Comment: You do not need `Case` to do that, use [`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx).

Comment: @MawiaHL good idead but how do I tell which type of user it is? I need to first look in the user table to know which user it is then select the remaining data from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to build the dataset in the `SELECT` part, but the `SELECT` part is only for altering the output, not the input and not for building a dataset.

The dataset is build using the `WHERE` statement in combination with crossselections with `JOIN`.

Aggregation can be done using `GROUP BY` but you do not need this by now.

```
   SELECT
          u.*,
          i.*,
          o.*
     FROM users u
LEFT JOIN individual i
       ON i.userFK = u.userFK
LEFT JOIN organization o
       ON o.userFK = u.userFK
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this

```
$userFk = $_POST['userFk'];
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT profilePhoto, userType FROM users WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $userFk);
if($stmt->execute())
{
$user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
$userType = $user['userType'];
if($userType == 1)
{
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT fname, lname From individual WHERE userFk = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $userFk);
    if($stmt->execute())
    {
      $details = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();  
      $user['fname'] =  $details['fname'];
        $user['lname'] =  $details['lname'];
    }
}else if($userType == 3)
{
     $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name From organization WHERE userFk = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $userFk);
    if($stmt->execute())
    {
      $details = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();  
      $user['organizationName'] =  $details['name'];

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your learning curve is a flat line when you circumvent the problem by adding unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @DanFromGermany well there is nothing I can do if people do not want to help, I mean this is all I can think of

Comment: People provided help in the comments. Don't use `CASE`, use two LEFT JOINS, `ON users.userFK = individual.userFK` and same with organization table.

Comment: @DanFromGermany if it was one table that would have worked, but the table to join entirely depends on the usertype in that user table, so either way I need to check the usertype before I can join, I am struggling with the method that checks if usertype is 1 or 3, I tried using if statement but it is also compilcated